# SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out

Tags: java

The following bit of code throws `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out`:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(6000);  
serverSocket.accept();
```

I have tried changing everything I can in creating a `ServerSocket` but the error remains the same. Please guide me in what I'm missing here, if anything.

Comment: Did you ping and check your specified InetAddress ?

Comment: You set a timeout, nothing happened,so you got a timeout. Why are you so surprised? If you don't want a timeout don't set one.

Answer (score 4):

What your code is doing is listening for 6 seconds for incoming TCP/IP requests on port zero for the local host<sup>1</sup>.

Here are some reasons why you might get a `SocketTimeoutException`.

- Nothing tries to connect to your service within the 6 second timeframe.
- Something tries to connect, but it is trying to connect on the wrong port.  (Port zero sounds to me like you are trying to accept requests on "any" port, and I think that is unlikely to work.)
- There is a software or hardware firewall (or packet filter) that is preventing connection requests from reaching your application, or is blocking the replies.

---

<sup>1 - If you don't want that "only accept an exception if it arrives within 6 seconds" behaviour ... which strikes me as a bit odd ... you shouldn't set a timeout on the server socket object.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I had tried spawning the JVM but that it was not done properly.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  What JVM are you talking about?